# How to remove/hide vertical and horizontal scrollbars from eclipse editor?

Tags: windows, eclipse, editor, customization

I'm using Eclipse and I would like to remove scrollbars from the editor.
(I usually partition my screen with multiple opened editors. I want to save space.).

Is there an easy way?

I'm using Windows 7.

Comment: I too would LOVE to know the answer to this.  Scrollbars are such a waste of precious screen space on a small laptop screen. I'm using Juno on Ubuntu 12.04.  At least Jeeeyul's Chrome Theme helps to make the sash narrow... but still can't get rid of that gd scrollbar! >_<

Answer (score 2):

That an oldie:

- [bug 27096](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=27096) mentions the presence of scrollbar for StyleText since 2003, and is a duplicate for:
- [bug 34928](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=34928) - Editors show scrollbars even when source has just 1 line with 1 char (also 2003)

Simply put, the `StyledText` widget has no API to show scrollbars only when necessary.
This is a SWT limitation.

Answer (score 1):

For all mac users:
Apple menu > System Preferences, then click General > Show scroll bars
Select “Automatically based on mouse or trackpad.” i voila :)

Comment: I had to change it to 'When scrolling', but this answer still helped me get rid of the unnecessary horizontal scrollbar, so thanks :)